# SceneKit crash when adding SCNPhysicsBallSocketJoint

Tags: ios, swift, crash, scenekit, arkit

I'm using ARKit and SceneKit to face tracking, so in some case I need to reset me scene. This is my code for resetting:

```
sceneView.scene.physicsWorld.removeAllBehaviors()

let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
```

Next step is setup my scene where I'm adding nodes and link them by **SCNPhysicsBallSocketJoint**. But this step causes the crash

```
Thread 8 name:  com.apple.scenekit.scnview-renderer  Dispatch queue: com.apple.scenekit.renderingQueue.ARSCNView0x153d0a8d0
Thread 8 Crashed:
0   SceneKit                        0x00000001bad70600 btUnionFind::unite+ 2950656 (int, int) + 8
1   SceneKit                        0x00000001bad705cc btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::calculateSimulationIslands+ 2950604 () + 296
2   SceneKit                        0x00000001bad6f218 btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::internalSingleStepSimulation+ 2945560 (float) + 136
3   SceneKit                        0x00000001bad6f138 btDiscreteDynamicsWorld::stepSimulation+ 2945336 (float, int, float) + 276
4   SceneKit                        0x00000001babb7334 -[SCNPhysicsWorld _step:] + 180
5   SceneKit                        0x00000001babff774 -[SCNRenderer _update:] + 964
6   SceneKit                        0x00000001bac01c50 -[SCNRenderer _drawSceneWithNewRenderer:] + 196
7   SceneKit                        0x00000001bac02208 -[SCNRenderer _drawScene:] + 48
8   SceneKit                        0x00000001bac025b0 -[SCNRenderer _drawAtTime:] + 636
9   SceneKit                        0x00000001bac9c9bc -[SCNView _drawAtTime:] + 452
10  ARKit                           0x00000001c275b9cc -[ARSCNView _drawAtTime:] + 40
11  SceneKit                        0x00000001bab638d0 __69-[NSObject+ 800976 (SCN_DisplayLinkExtensions)
```

it is strange that at first time scene setup there is no crash when adding **SCNPhysicsBallSocketJoint** joints to nodes. I think maybe there is the reason in wrong reset the scene. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The nodes in SCNPhysicsBallSocketJoint should have  physicalBodyies.